# Will spring.servlet.multipart.* properties apply to Jersey multipart?

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, multipartform-data

I've got a spring boot application which uses Jersey. I've got the following properties in `application.properties`:

```
# Enable multipart.
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true

# Write files larger than 1MB to disk (instead of memory).
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=1MB

# Set location for multipart file uploads.
spring.servlet.multipart.location=/tmp/tomcat

# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize=100MB

# Max request size.
spring.servlet.multipart.maxRequestSize=100MB

# Set max header size
server.max-http-header-size=65536
```

I have enabled Jersey multipart with `register(MultiPartFeature.class);`.

It seems to me that Jersey is not picking up / not configured with the multipart values set via `spring.servlet.multipart.*`. When I upload a large file to the application, it creates a corresponding `/tmp/MIME*` file, and not into `/tmp/tomcat` as specified in `application.properties`.

It appears that Jersey by default expects a `jersey-multipart-config.properties` file in `WEB-INF/classes` where it can pick up properties.

I'd really like Jersey to pick up on the properties given in `application.properties`. Is that possible, or will I have to accept that I need to manage multipart properties in a separate configuration file?

Comment: No they don't apply, they apply to the multipart resolver in Spring not the external configuration for Jersey you will need to configure that yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks. If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spring.servlet.multipart` applies to the `MultipartResolver` support in Spring MVC. It will be registered with an `MultipartConfigElement` which in turn will be added to any servlet available in the context (see [the javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MultipartAutoConfiguration.html)).

It won't apply to the jersey configuration as that is seperated and probably applies to a filter (in the end). You might be able to reuse the configuration properties or even obtain the pre-configured `MultipartConfigElement` to obtain the configuration.

Nonetheless you will need to manually put in the configuration.